# Adds 1 unit of an item to the cart with quantity selector set to "0"

Tags: product, cart

Users on a product page with the quantity selector set to "0" units still can add 1 unit to the shooping cart after clicking the "add to the cart" button. The button is not checking for any rule that says that no units are selected therefore you cannot add any product to the shopping cart. Any help to fix this is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento will automatically assume "1" if you have your minimum amount to add to cart set to "0". If you have available inventory and want to make a sale, this shouldn't be an issue for you.

If you are using the 'minimum qty to add to cart' function as a means of limiting whether a customer can buy a product from you, you are doing it wrong. You can choose to disable the product, assign its stock status to "out of stock," and/or assign its inventory to "0" to prevent your customer from buying something.

These setting can be set globally for all products via System > Configuration > Inventory in your admin area.

You can override any of these settings in an individual product record under the Inventory tab as well.